# How to dynamically supply value variables to a DataFrame groupby in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably very straightforward, but I've been staring at the pandas repo and searching on here for ages.

I have a straightforward groupby, for multiple value columns:

```
df = df.groupby(['dim1', 'dim2'])["metric1", "metric2"].sum()
```

I want to populate this dynamically. I can do:

```
dimensions = ['dim1', 'dim2']
df = df.groupby(dimensions)["metric1", "metric2"].sum()
```

but I can't figure out what exactly is happening in the final line where the metrics are stated.

I don't have a thorough understanding of Python's workings behind the scenes (stuff like what's actually happening when applying common syntax like accessing dict values), but it seems like this is similar to accessing a dict value, and playing around with the `__getattr__` method works for a single value, but not a list of two.

An explanation of how this works and can be achieved would be amazing. Presumably I can replace the `["metric1", "metric2"]` in the final line with a groupby method, but which?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but seems like 'metrics' can be variable in length and in values, right? You can achieve a dynamic approach by using `operator.attrgetter`

```
dimensions = ['dim1', 'dim2']
metrics = ["metric1", "metric2"]
df = attrgetter(*metrics)(df.groupby(dimensions)).sum()
```